# Transferring a file through the CLI on the same network

Tags: networking, command-line-interface, file-transfer

I have a file on my desktop and I need to get it onto another server, but I have no means of getting it there, i.e. email/usb or any way like that.
The server is on the same network as me.

I have heard of a way that the file can be copied via the command line.

Would anyone have any information on this and if so could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether you have command line access to that server or not? If yes, are you accessing it via telnet or via ssh?

If ssh, you should be able to transfer the file via SCP (secure copy), since it uses the same ssh connection you use to get your cli. If you want to transfer your file *from* a Windows environment, you may want to look at WinSCP, else do a `man scp` on your Linux or Unix server and, assuming you have it, you'll get the hang of it... it's not complicated.

If ssh is not an option, then you depend on the server having some service available for you to transfer the file, most obvious one being FTP.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for that, I had a look into scp and got the file transferred